# Wave Equation with outgoing wave boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-series, laplace-transform

I need some help with this problem: I have a to solve the wave equation with two initial conditions and with outgoing wave boundary conditions; i.e.,

$$\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-u_{xx} & =0\\
u(x,0) & =Ae^{\frac{(x-x_{0})2}{\sigma^{2}}}\\
u_{t}(0,t) & =u_{x}(0,t)\\
u_{t}(1,t) & =-u_{x}(1,t)
\end{cases}
 $$
I need to get the exact solution, to verify a program that I'm making.

what I know is that :$$u(x,t)=f(x-t)+g(x-t)$$

and I should proceed defining:
$$u_{t}(0,x)=\phi(x)$$

and make $\phi$ in such way that the boundary condition are met.

I have try this but I'm really stuck :(.

Some help or reference will be very nice.

Thanks

Comment: The boundary conditions you are using, are called "Transparent boundary condition". In fact you'r equation is the tipical IVP  wave equation. Thus I dont really know how to deduce those "boundary condition".